# Polymer: can't get this.__data__ passing in from host

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer-1.0, dataflow, html-imports

I have a very simple project:

```
app/
    parent.html
    child.html
index.html
```

I try to pass data from parent to child and then get them within Polymer():

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="app/parent.html"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Paul!</h1>
    <x-comphost></x-comphost>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app/parent.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="child.html"/>
<dom-module id="x-comphost" noscript>
  <template>
    <h4>Hello, man!</h4>
    <p>I'm seeking a child</p>
    <x-child accessible-policies="{{policies}}"></x-child>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "x-comphost",
      ready: function(){
        this.policies = ['Hospital', 'Dental', 'Travel'];
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**app/child.html**

```
<dom-module id="x-child" noscript>
    <template>
        [[accessiblePolicies]]
        <h5>Hello again!</h5>
        <p>Remember me?</p>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "x-child",
            properties: {},
            ready: function () {
                console.log('thisData', this.__data__);
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The trouble is that Polymer sees `this.__data__` only if data being transmitted from host is declared implicitly like above, next to template opener tag. If I remove it from there it can't see it. So it looks like a trick. I don't want to place that data within template, I want use it within the `Polymer` function. But I don't know how to achive this properly, what is the right way without any tricks.
I believe somebody knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data via javascript interface, just add the following to your parent (`x-comphost`) implementation:

```
Polymer({
  is: "x-comphost",
  ready: function(){
    this.policies = ['Hospital', 'Dental', 'Travel'];

    /* Query shadow DOM for the x-child element */
    var childEl = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('x-child');

    childEl.accessiblePolicies = this.policies;
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, I've got data, but not inside this.__data__ as I presumed, but like this.accessiblePolicies. It will took some time however in order to understand everything.

Comment: Btw, it is possible even not to pass data at all, using this.domHost in child instead.

Comment: Even though it works i would recommend not using this until necessary as this is basically piercing shadow-dom, a loophole that was intentionally left open by Polymer due to unavailability of Shadow-dom V0 in all browsers for performance reasons. But with shadow-dom V1 almost implemented in all major browsers and Polymer 2.0 close to release this will be deprecated. You can read about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/2016-09-09-polymer-2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Configure Policies in properties object instead of ready cycle in parent and as per Parent attribute name make properties in child , mentioned in below code

Parent.html

Polymer({
      is: "x-comphost",

```
  properties :{

    policies : {
      type : Array,
      value : ['Hospital', 'Dental', 'Travel']
    }
  },
  ready: function(){
  //  this.policies = ['Hospital', 'Dental', 'Travel'];

  }
});
```

Child.html

Polymer({
            is: "x-child",

```
        properties: {
            accessiblePolicies : {
                type : Array,
                value : []                }

        },
        ready: function () {
            console.log('thisData', this.accessiblePolicies);
        }
    });
```