# How to get Polymer domHost property?

Tags: javascript, api, oop, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a basic Polymer template with a very simple structure, described here:
[Polymer: can't get this.__data__ passing in from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478627/polymer-cant-get-this-data-passing-in-from-host/39493565) (codebase is here: https://srgg6701.github.io/Polymer_template)
I need to use data passed from parent to children. I can pass them and see it within `this.domHost`:

[image]

However, if I try to get `this.domHost.properties`, it says `undefined` (!).

[image]

So, two questions:

1. Why it is undefined here?
2. Is it possible to make this data accessible?

Comment: I updated my Answer to answer to your two questions too with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

**For Question#1:** It's most likely copy of the element before the ready event, thats why it is undefined. Most of the cases you should use the [Polymer DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom) to manipulate in the DOM. The Host Object should be available in: `Polymer.dom(this).getOwnerRoot().host`

**For Question#2:** Use [Polymer Data Binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding) for this kind of job what you want achieve. You can still use the `this.policies` in the parent element, but the Data Binder will give information to the child elements and everything will be synchronized and handled.

For the data binding, add a property to your `x-comphost` and `x-child` element:

```
properties: {
    data: {
        type: Object,
        value: null, // Default Value

        // Fire value-changed Event when changed
        // so the elements and the data binding
        // will react to that.
        notify: true

        // (optional) Listener for the property changing
        // if your want to make custom logic
        observer: '_doSomething' 
    }
}
```

And in themplate add the attribute like this: `<x-child data="{{data}}"></x-child>`

With more elements you can make a [Behavior](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors) which can contain the property and the observer details and you not need to copy-paste to every element but you can override if you want:

```
var MyDataBehavior = {
    properties: {
        data: {type:Object, notify:true, observer: '_dataChanged'}
    },
    dataChanged: function( data ) { /* ... */ }
};
```

After you added the behavior input then just add it to your element definition:

```
//...
behaviors: [MyDataBehavior],
//...
```

Shadow DOM is similar a closed Castle where you cannot enter or leave from inside, you have to build bridges to let peoples in and out.

> *Monica Dinculescu (from Google Polymer team):*
>
> **Make bridges instead of dragons to enter the Shadow DOM castle!**

Ultimatley you can add your data into the global scope and you can reach it, because the window object is shared, not some kind of copy of the original one.